# Rotate bitmap on canvas in android

Tags: android

I have a problem to rotate bitmap on canvas ,I am drawing bitmap on canvas by using canvas.drawline and use following code to rotate image

It rotate but it shows two image now ?How to remove previous image from canvas? What to do?

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) /*getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()*/600, (int) /*getWindowManager()
                        .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()*/600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
             Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
             drawingImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

              // canvas.rotate(90);
                   for(int i=0;i<SettingsStaticData.arrX1_crossPoint.size();i++)
                   {

                       canvas.drawLine(new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrX1_crossPoint.get(i)),new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrY1_crossPoint.get(i)),new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrX2_crossPoint.get(i)) ,new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrY2_crossPoint.get(i)), paint);


                   }


                    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 0.9);
                   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                 //  paint.setColor(Color.RED);

                   paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
               for(int i=0;i<arrXX.size()-1;i++)
                {

                  if(i==arrXX.size()-2)
                  {
                      canvas.drawLine(new Float(arrXX.get(0)),new Float(arrYY.get(0)),new Float(arrXX.get(i+1)) ,new Float(arrYY.get(i+1)), paint);
                      canvas.drawLine(new Float(arrXX.get(i)),new Float(arrYY.get(i)),new Float(arrXX.get(i+1)) ,new Float(arrYY.get(i+1)), paint);

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      canvas.drawLine(new Float(arrXX.get(i)),new Float(arrYY.get(i)),new Float(arrXX.get(i+1)) ,new Float(arrYY.get(i+1)), paint);

                  }
                }


        //     canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
               Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                  matrix.reset();
               matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth() / 2-500, -bitmap.getHeight() / 2-500); // Centers image
               matrix.postRotate(180);
              //matrix.postTranslate(px, py);


               canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the last line: `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);`

`canvas` is initialized with the `bitmap` so you draw the bitmap on itself (with some changes).

Just create another `Canvas canvas2` and change the last line to `canvas2.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);`  and display the last one `drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);` where bitmap2 is the bitmap used to create canvas2.

So, explicitly:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) /*getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()*/600, (int) /*getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()*/600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
bitmapFinal = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) /*getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()*/600, (int) /*getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()*/600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // canvas.rotate(90);
    for(int i=0;i<SettingsStaticData.arrX1_crossPoint.size();i++){
        canvas.drawLine(new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrX1_crossPoint.get(i)),
                new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrY1_crossPoint.get(i)),
                new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrX2_crossPoint.get(i)) ,
                new Float(SettingsStaticData.arrY2_crossPoint.get(i)), paint);
    }

    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 0.9);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    //  paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#800080"));
    for(int i=0;i<arrXX.size()-1;i++){

        if(i==arrXX.size()-2){
            canvas.drawLine(new Float(arrXX.get(0)),new Float(arrYY.get(0)),
                    new Float(arrXX.get(i+1)) ,new Float(arrYY.get(i+1)), paint);
            canvas.drawLine(new Float(arrXX.get(i)),new Float(arrYY.get(i)),
                    new Float(arrXX.get(i+1)) ,new Float(arrYY.get(i+1)), paint);

        }else{
            canvas.drawLine(new Float(arrXX.get(i)),new Float(arrYY.get(i)),new Float(arrXX.get(i+1)) ,new Float(arrYY.get(i+1)), paint);
        }
    }
    //     canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth() / 2-500, -bitmap.getHeight() / 2-500); // Centers image
    matrix.postRotate(180);
    //matrix.postTranslate(px, py);

    Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bitmapFinal);
    canvas2.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
    drawingImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapFinal);
```

Also, my advice is to look for a better place to create the bitmaps - you don't really need to create a new bitmap every time - you should create them once and reuse (it is expensive to continually create bitmaps). I would sugest `onCreate()` function for this purpose.

Comment: hii thanks for answer
i have tryied this code bt its not drawing seond image  Canvas canvas2=new Canvas(bitmap1);
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    
               matrix.reset();
      matrix.postTranslate(/*-bitmap.getWidth() / 2*/-500, /*-bitmap.getHeight() / 2*/-500); // Centers image
      matrix.postRotate(180);
     //matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
      
      canvas2.drawBitmap(bitmap1, matrix, null);
       
      drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1); please help